# How can I see property value which is used by the Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-selectors, cypress

I am working on Cypress example shown on the page https://example.cypress.io/commands/querying:

```
cy.get('[data-test-id="test-example"]')
  .invoke('css', 'position')
  .should('equal', 'static')
```

Using Google Dev Tools I can not find css property **position: static** of the correspondent div element located on this page. The given div, cypress code and correspondent Google Dev info are marked red:

[image: Screenshot related to the question]

The test passes and confirms the value. How can I see it in Google Dev Tools?

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html - it's calling the css method (from jQuery https://api.jquery.com/css/) with the argument "position".

Comment: Please, have a look at my question and you'll see that it is NOT about using invoke method I know what is it for. I am asking about the position property used by it because Google Dev Tools do not show it anywhere (I mean position: static).

Comment: It's unclear where you've been looking. Note that static is the default position anyway, per e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

Comment: You're looking at the properties, not the *styles*. Look in the Computed tab.

Comment: I have looked everywhere and in the Styles as well. It is so easy - just use the url provided be me and check yourself.

Comment: That's not what you're showing, though; if you'd looked somewhere where it's reasonable to expect it to be, *show that*, but there's no point showing that it's not where it's obviously not going to be.

Comment: I guess I should not show anything except of the URL, target div and cypress code. That is more than enough. Is not it? Please show me the place where the mentioned property is shown. The URL once more: https://example.cypress.io/commands/querying:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody. So if you need to get CSS property and can't find it anywhere, just check if the "Show all" checkbox is checked in the Computed tab of your Google dev tool:
[image]